# How can I import class instance from file to use in class method in Python?

Tags: class, python-3.x, file-io

I'm studying my first programming course in college and I have created a class for the teams in a soccer league. I want to import premade class instances from a file different from the file I store my class and its methods in. Ideal would be for the instances to be imported and utilized in the certain method I called it for, and then later be saved back to the original file again? Is there any smart ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Use the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module? Or make the file itself a module (but pre-made instances may not be a good idea inside a module).

Comment: ``from other_file import PremadeClass`` ?!? Could you please rephrase the question?